# Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish no longer works after locker service was enabled

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, locker-service

Created a VF Page to initialize the App:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" standardController="CustomObject">  
   <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js"/>
   <apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/29.0/publisher-min.js"/>
    <div id="lightning"/>
    <div>
        <script>
            var recordId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
            $Lightning.use("c:LightningApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:LightningComponent",
                  { "recordId" : recordId },
                  "lightning",
                  function(cmp) {                      
                      console.log("Component created!");
                      console.log(cmp);
                  });
            });

        </script>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

On the lightning Component created a cancel button:

```
<button aura:id="cancelButton" class="formButton floatLeft" style="float:left" onclick="{!c.cancel}">{!$Label.c.CancelButton}</button>
```

On the Cancel controller:

```
cancel : function(component, event, helper){
   sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close",payload:{ refresh:"true" }});
```

Before locker service was enabled it was working fine but now it is not. Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Comment: Hi @Doug Chasman is there a fix/work around  for the issue above?